# How to change the message(body) of AlertDialog in onPrepareDialog()?

Tags: android

Will you please anyone let me know how to change the Message (Body) of an alert dialog in onPrepareDialog().

I am not able to find any function like setText() even after typecasting the Dialog parament in the onPrepareDialog() function.

I dont want to use
removeDialog()
showDialog()
as it will be overhead to GC to clean the objects and if i go for custom dialog then code becomes huge for handling in case of themes.

Please let me know if anyone have idea of changing the text of an AlertDialog in the onPrepareDialog() function.

Thanks & Regards,
SSuman185

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Within `onPrepareDialog` just use:

```
((AlertDialog) dialog).setMessage("my text goes here");
```

Comment: Note that for this to work, you must initialize the message with a non-null value in onCreateDialog. See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6489